# Best way to store multiple date in one object django

Tags: django, performance, django-models

I have model Topic. Now i have date = models.DateTimeField

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.SET(GUEST_ID))
    seminar = models.ForeignKey(Seminar, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(default='')
    speaker_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

but i want to save multiple date for example: 27.11.2022,29.11.2022,01.01.2023. I have idea to write
`date = models.CharField()`
and save dates as string

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `JsonField` would give you a good flexibility to store unstructured data.

For example:

```py
class Topic(models.Model):
    ...
    dates = models.JsonField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Then you can save your dates like:

```py
{
"date_title_one": "some_data",
"date_title_two": "some_data_2"
}
```

Read about [JsonField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.JSONField)